# Issue in adding form controls using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms-designer

hi all i am try to add some form controls using C#. i am very much new in windows application.
i have a main form. and its class is is like that,

```
  private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        var Painter = new Painter();
        Painter.Paint();
    }
```

i have to add many textboxes and labels using programmically (can't dragging from toolbar). so i created another class, Painter.CS

```
class Painter
{
    Label label1;
    TextBox txtbx1;
    public void Paint(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1 = new Label();
        txtbx1 = new TextBox();
        label1.UseMnemonic = true;
        label1.Text = "First &Name:";
        label1.Location = new Point(15, 15);
        label1.BackColor = Color.Pink;
        label1.ForeColor = Color.Maroon;
        label1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        label1.Size = new Size(label1.PreferredWidth, label1.PreferredHeight + 2);
        txtbx1.Text = "Enter Your Name";
        txtbx1.Location = new Point(15 + label1.PreferredWidth + 5, 15);
        txtbx1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        txtbx1.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        txtbx1.ForeColor = Color.Maroon;
        txtbx1.Size = new Size(90, 20);
        Main.Controls.Add(label1);    //i dont know how to add this in main form
        Main.Controls.Add(txtbx1);
    }
}
```

i cant add this label and text box in my main form. Please help me.

Comment: You have to use the instance of your main class, not the class. As I understand from your code "Main" is your class name.

Comment: ya main is my first form name and main.cs is its class

Comment: If you still want to do it this way modify your paint method like this:  public void Paint(Form main)
    {  // main.Controls.Add(..)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ed S. pointed out is not a good way to do it like this, but to fix your code try:

```
private Painter _painter;
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    //...    
    _painter = new Painter();
    _painter.Paint(this);
}

class Painter
{
   public void Paint(Form main)
   {   
//... 

    main.Controls.Add(label1);    
    main.Controls.Add(txtbx1);

//...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to access a static property `Controls` on the `Main` class, but no such property exists. It wouldn't make sense either as controls belong to an *instance* of your form class.

Your entire `Painter` class is superfluous.  Just add your controls in your Form's constructor.

```
public class Main : Form
{
    public Form() 
    {
        SuspendLayout();
        var label1 = new Label();
        var txtbx1 = new TextBox();
        label1.UseMnemonic = true;
        label1.Text = "First &Name:";
        label1.Location = new Point(15, 15);
        label1.BackColor = Color.Pink;
        label1.ForeColor = Color.Maroon;
        label1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        label1.Size = new Size(label1.PreferredWidth, label1.PreferredHeight + 2);
        txtbx1.Text = "Enter Your Name";
        txtbx1.Location = new Point(15 + label1.PreferredWidth + 5, 15);
        txtbx1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        txtbx1.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        txtbx1.ForeColor = Color.Maroon;
        txtbx1.Size = new Size(90, 20);
        Controls.Add(label1); 
        Controls.Add(txtbx1);
        ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

This is where that code belongs anyway. Your form should be responsible for its layout, not some other class.  This is how the designer would have done it.

A partial class would have been created with a method named `InitializeComponent` which creates and lays out the controls.  It would have been called from the constructor.